# Wordpress Ajax Callback

Tags: plugins, php, ajax

I want your help as I am new in Ajax and Wordpress. This is a simple plugin and I want to know what I am doing wrong and getting "zero" result

> ajax.php

```
    add_shortcode( 'ajax_shortcode', 'ajax_shortcode_function' );

  function ajax_shortcode_function() {
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  wp_register_script ('ajax_script', plugins_url( '/ajax.js', __FILE__ ), plugins_url( '/ajax.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'));
  wp_enqueue_script ( 'ajax_script' );
  wp_localize_script ( 'ajax_script', 'ajax', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));


  function my_submit_process() {
    global $wpdb;
    $text1 = $_POST['text1'];
    $text2 = $_POST['text2'];

    echo $text1 + $text2;
    wp_die();
echo 'sfdasdfsdfsdfas';
echo $text1 + $text2;
  }

  add_action('wp_ajax_submit_process', 'my_submit_process');
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_submit_process', 'my_submit_process');
?>
<input type="text" id="text1"> +
<input type="text" id="text2">
<button id="button"> = </button>
<div id="result"></div>
<?php
}
```

> ajax.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('#button').click(function(e) {
    var val1 = $('#text1').val();
    var val2 = $('#text2').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajax.ajax_url,
        data: { action: 'submit_process', text1: val1, text2: val2 },
        success: function(response) {

            $('#result').html(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: I would drop set JS aside for starters and try to just make manual request to `admin_ajax.php` and dump what happens in your handler.

Answer (score 1):

It looks odd to me that your `ajax_shortcode_function()` registers and enqueues your ajax script. According to the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), you should register/enqueue in functions.php. Additionally, if you only need the url to ajax-admin.php, the tutorial says you can use the global `ajaxurl` variable and therefore you don't need to localize your script.

The other thing that looks odd is `my_submit_process()` seems to be located *within* `ajax_shortcode_function()`. I'd check that the closing brace is in the correct location and try again if it isn't.

Comment: You need to know that ajaxurl is only for backend.

NOTE: Since Version 2.8, The JavaScript global variable `ajaxurl` can be used in case you want to separate your JavaScript code from php files into JavaScript only files. This is true on the administration side only. If you are using AJAX on the front-end, you need to make your JavaScript aware of the `admin-ajax.php url`. A best practice is documented in the fourth example, below using `wp_localize_script().`

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using wp_die(). I would put a die() at the end of the method instead of a wp_die() in the middle like that. I don't know if it would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw that in `wp_register_script` i have

```
plugins_url( '/ajax.js', __FILE__ )
```

twice. I removed it and I get the `0` result again